# APIGEE - Cookies Issue

Tags: session, apigee

Cookies support  - Problem?

Original Issue/Background:

We have API based on servlet / JSON running in Openshift, the web server used in openshift is Tomcat.

We store information to httpsession and everything works fine when used directly against openshift / tomcat (POST / GET). But when we configured apigee against existing methods the session is lost. Stuff is stored correctly in the session in server side, but when second request comes from apigee into the tomcat the session is "lost"

Piece of java code to get the session is plain httpsession.getRequest(). As said this works fine when using backend directly. Is there some additional steps (cookies etc) needed to maintain the session when requests are used through apigee?

Update Findings;

With short debug an traffic monitoring the reason of the error in apigee is confirmed to be that it does not pass JSessionId to requests. This means that cookies support should be enabled somehow in the API proxy settings / Configuration.

Anyone have an idea where or if this can be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

First off, cookies aren't part of a proper RESTful payload -- if you grabbed the headers you could store them with an access_token as part of the generate token policies.

That aside, you should be able to pass the cookies back to the requesting App and then let the app pass them back to the API -- my jokeindex API lets you do this.

Make sure you don't have any AssignMessage policies in the flow that are stripping out the headers accidentally -- something like this:

```
<Set>
  <Headers />
</Set>
```

as that will remove ALL headers. Also, you can look at the Trace tool in Apigee to check each policy step along the way to see if you're stripping the Cookie: header from the requesting payload.

Answer (score 1):

When you have your resource on address "http://yourdomain.com/somewhere/", and you redirect to that resource from apigee API, for instance by url: http://yourapi.apigee.net/v0/myresource" what you get back from your server is cookie for /somewhere/ not v0/resource/somewhere, so basically when browser gets cookie back, it does not put it into correct place and discards it. At least that was/is my case.

Answer (score 0):

You should ping @bissell about this but I did find this article that might be helpful: 
http://community.apigee.com/groups/learn-create-and-manage-apis/some-basic-questions-new

Also, you might be able to fix your issue by adding an "extract variable" policy to the request that captures the JSessionId and then adding an "assign message" policy to add it back to the request.

You can assign policies from API Platform>Dashboard>API Proxies>YOUR API>Develop